# Ubuntu 20.04 - Curl: symbol lookup error

Tags: 20.04, libraries, curl

I set up a new version of ubuntu on a laptop. Post that, in order to set it up identical to my desktop, I did an apt clone and install

```
# Take a backup of the entire apt repo using apt-clone
    sudo apt-clone clone "$BACKUP_DIR"/apt-clone-"$(date +%Y%m%dT%H.%M.%S)".tar.gz
# Get a dump of Dconf settings
    dconf dump / >"$BACKUP_DIR"/dconf_settings.dconf

# Restore
# Do a restore
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive sudo apt-clone restore "$BACKUP_DIR"/apt-clone*tar.gz

#reload the dconf
    dconf load / <"$BACKUP_DIR"/dconf_settings.dconf
```

Everything seemingly went well with it. However, when I run curl, I get the below error:

```
curl: symbol lookup error: curl: undefined symbol: curl_url_set, version CURL_OPENSSL_4
```

I looked up the issue in SO / ask ubuntu and ran the below:

```
$ sudo ldd $(which curl) | grep libcurl

    libcurl.so.4 => /usr/lib/dcaenabler/libcurl.so.4 (0x00....)
```

```
$ ls -ltr /usr/lib/dcaenabler/libcurl*

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 518600 Jan 29  2021 /usr/lib/dcaenabler/libcurl.so.4.5.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 Aug 15 21:15 /usr/lib/dcaenabler/libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.5.0
```

I removed the soft link and replaced with the libcurl.so.4 present in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4 /usr/lib/dcaenabler/
```

Curl began to work like normal after this.

**HOWEVER**

This doesn't seem to survive a reboot. Nor does it survive if I for whatever reason run `ldconfig`

How do I permanently fix this?

Comment: Do you really know who, why and when created a `/usr/lib/dcaenabler/` directory? Where it is defined? What do you have for `dpkg -S dcaenabler`?

Comment: Do you run this on Dell laptop?

Comment: Yes. Dell laptop with ubuntu preinstalled. I guess that's where the ```/usr/lib/dcaenabler comes``` from

Comment: I suppose it's this -- https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-in/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=14g99

Answer (score 7):

The Dell DCA enabler packages cause this issue. To fix the system we need to remove them by running

```
sudo apt-get purge --autoremove dca-enabler-packages dca-enabler
```

Comment: Removing the DCA packages fixed a lot of stuff, including `curl`, on my D17S tower. Thanks!