# curl: symbol lookup error

Tags: curl

I'm having problems installing curl on a laptop running Ubuntu 20.04.

I simply run

`sudo apt install curl`
And it all seemed to work:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  curl
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/162 kB of archives.
After this operation, 412 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package curl.
(Reading database ... 245012 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../curl_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.11_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking curl (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.11) ...
Setting up curl (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.11) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
```

But when I run anything related to curl (such as `curl version`), I get the message

`curl: symbol lookup error: curl: undefined symbol: curl_url_set, version CURL_OPENSSL_4`
I've already tried a couple of suggestions on SO, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69255382/curl-symbol-lookup-error-curl-undefined-symbol-curl-url-cleanup

If it helps, here are some of the outputs asked in the above question:

```
rodrigo@rodrigo-ThinkPad-T430s:~$ which curl
/usr/bin/curl
rodrigo@rodrigo-ThinkPad-T430s:~$ echo $PATH
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:/home/rodrigo/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
rodrigo@rodrigo-ThinkPad-T430s:~$ alias curl
bash: alias: curl: not found
```

---

After a previous question on SO, I was suggested to follow this:
[Ubuntu 20.04 - Curl: symbol lookup error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1358184/ubuntu-20-04-curl-symbol-lookup-error)

Running `ln -s /bin/curl /usr/bin/curl` returned me `ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/curl': File exists.`

Here are some of the outputs from the question above:

```
rodrigo@rodrigo-ThinkPad-T430s:~$ sudo ldd $(which curl) | grep libcurl
libcurl.so.4 => /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007f7120478000)
rodrigo@rodrigo-ThinkPad-T430s:~$ ls -ltr 
/usr/local/lib/libcurl* -rwxrw-rw- 1 root root 518600 mai 17 00:24 /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4.5.0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 mai 17 10:32 /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.5.0
```

Comment: `/usr/local/lib/`? Did you install curl from source?

Comment: Not really. Just a plain `sudo apt install curl`!

Comment: Well then did you install something else from source?

Comment: I'm now lost with what exactly I did before that, but it may have been the installation of `homebrew`. It seems to be installed, but it can't find `curl`... ```rodrigo@rodrigo-ThinkPad-T430s:~$ brew version
Error: Please update your system curl.
Minimum required version: 7.41.0
Your curl version: 
Your curl executable: 
Error: Unknown command: version```