# Programs not showing after purge DCA Enabler

Tags: 22.04, dell

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 300 with Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.
I installed Ruby and Rails and when I was launching the server I had a symbol lookup error.

After searching in many webs I found many answers saying that it was due to Dells laptop having a software called DCA Enabler and that by removing it everything would be solved.
[Ubuntu 20.04 - Curl: symbol lookup error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1358184/ubuntu-20-04-curl-symbol-lookup-error)

So after running the commnad `sudo apt-get purge --autoremove dca-enabler-packages dca-enabler` almost all of the programs I installed with Ubuntu Software disappeared. If I look for them they dont show, calling them from the terminal wont do anything, icons from sidebar in favorites disappared.
Only Filezilla stayed showing and working, I dont know why.

After turning the computer off, now I get kernel panic messages and wont boot.

I have no problem in formatting the disks and doing a new Ubuntu installation, the computer didnt have anything important.

The problem is that Im pretty sure I will get the same symbol lookup error and dont know how to make it work.

Thank you for your time,
Leo